# Change optimizer alghoritm in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

If you change the optimizer in Keras, you need to compile your model again. This compilation overrides the learned weights of the network. I know how to save weights, but I do not know how to restore them for a network. Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will get a better response if you provide a detailed explanation of what you have tried so far, and any example code that illustrates the issue you are seeing. Can you show us what you have attempted for restoring your network weights?

Comment: No, this compilation does not override the weights.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a YouTube video that explains exactly what you're wanting to do: [Save and load a Keras model](https://youtu.be/7n1SpeudvAE)

How you load the model weights is going to depend on how you saved the model or model weights. There are three different saving methods that Keras makes available. These are described in the video link above (with examples), as well as below.

1. The `model.save('my_model.h5')` function saves:

   - The architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model.
   - The weights of the model.
   - The training configuration (loss, optimizer).
   - The state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

   To load this saved model, you would use the following:

   ```
   from keras.models import load_model
   new_model = load_model('my_model.h5')
   ```
2. The `model.to_json()` function only saves the architecture of the model. This will **not** save the weights. To load this saved model, you would use the following:

   ```
   json_string = model.to_json()

   from keras.models import model_from_json
   model = model_from_json(json_string)
   ```
3. The `model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')` function only saves the weights of the model. To load these saved weights to a model, you would use the following:

   ```
   model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
   ```